# angular2 rxjs observable create not inherting functions from import

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

If I create an observable via the constructor or via the static `create` function, I am noticing that any additional functions I import are not being added to the prototype? What am I doing wrong? E.g.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

let observable = Observable.create(observer => {
    observer.complete();
});

// observable.map is undefined, not on the prototype
```

**Edit**

Ok, thanks to the link from Pankaj Parkar, If I import the entire library `rxjs/Rx` then it works. Evidently I must be missing another import?

Comment: I think [this comment](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/750#issuecomment-157898124) on github issue can be helpful

Comment: Sort of helped! Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Rx.all? if so I just use import {Rx} from 'rx';